# Cleaning out bad JSON data from object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-cleaning

I am retrieving building geolocation data from a service, however in some cases some of the data will have missing properties.

**Good data**

```
[{
    "ModifiedOn": "2015-04-29 11:17:28.0",
    "BuildingName": "Wintefell",
    "Latitude": "52.900619",
    "Longitude": "-1.434602",
    "Region": "The North",
}, {
    "ModifiedOn": "2015-04-29 11:17:28.0",
    "BuildingName": "Water Gardens",
    "Latitude": "51.818051",
    "Longitude": "-.354871",
    "Region": "Dorne"
}]
```

**Bad data**

Missing Region or Building Name

```
{
    "ModifiedOn": "2015-04-29 11:17:28.0",
    "BuildingName": "Kings Landing",
    "Latitude": "23.818051",
    "Longitude": "-.154871",
}
```

After making my AJAX request I store the JSON response in an object called *_regionAndBuildings*

I want to clean out any bad data from it, so I tried the following code

```
console.log("Starting size of building data : " + _regionAndBuildings.length);
//clean json by setting object to undefined
for (var i = 0; i < _regionAndBuildings.length; i++) {
    if (_regionAndBuildings[i].BuildingName === undefined && _regionAndBuildings[i].Region === undefined) {
        console.log("Deleting");
        delete _regionAndBuildings[i];
    }
}
console.log("Ending size of building data after cleaning : " + _regionAndBuildings.length);
```

**Output**

> Starting size : 209
>
> Delete x 17
>
> Ending size : 209

Why is this code not removing the bad elements in my JSON object?

Comment: Try using `array.splice` instead of delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. As per the question

   > Missing Region or Building Name

   You want to remove the elements of either Region or Building Name is missing. But the condition doesn't reflect that

   ```
   if (_regionAndBuildings[i].BuildingName === undefined && 
       _regionAndBuildings[i].Region === undefined)
   ```

   Since you have used `&&` operator, only when both the expressions are satisfied, the code inside `if` condition will be executed. So, you need to change it with logical OR operator `||`, like this

   ```
   if (_regionAndBuildings[i].BuildingName === undefined ||
       _regionAndBuildings[i].Region === undefined)
   ```
2. When you use `delete` operator on an array, the element in the array will be deleted, but the index will point to nothing. It means the length of the array will not change. Read more about it in [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements_)

   Instead, you can use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), like this

   ```
   _regionAndBuildings.splice(i, 1);
   ```

---

But, I prefer reconstructing the array without the elements you don't want, with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this

```
var filteredBuildings = _regionAndBuildings.filter(function (currentObject) {
    return currentObject.hasOwnProperty("BuildingName") &&
        currentObject.hasOwnProperty("Region");
});
```

Now, the function passed will be run with all the items in the array and only if the function returns `true`, the object will be included in the filtered result. So, if the object has both `BuildingName` and `Region` properties, only then it will be included in the result.

---

**Note:** I prefer using [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the property exists in the object, rather than comparing the value against `undefined`, because if the value of the property is actually `undefined`, then we cannot differentiate between a non-existing property and a property with value `undefined`.

Comment: What do you think about checking the size of each object? if I know that good data has 6 properties. So if property size is less than 6.

Comment: @loosebruce But then you will not know which of the properties are missing, right?

Answer (score 2):

The first reason - you use `&&` instead of `||` there:

```
_regionAndBuildings[i].BuildingName === undefined && _regionAndBuildings[i].Region === undefined
```

But you said:

> Bad data
>
> Missing Region **or** Building Name

The second reason - when you delete elements from array by `delete`, you get a gap `undefined`:

```
[<elem>, undefined, <elem>]
```

Elem was removed, but length will be the same.
You can remove `undefined` by `filter` later:

```
var newArray = yourArray.filter(function(item) { return item});
```

But best way is use `slice` instead of `delete`:

```
_regionAndBuildings.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: Instead of `||` you could use `if (!(arr[i].BuildingName && !arr[i].Region))` too.

Answer (score 1):

can you try :

```
if (typeof _regionAndBuildings[i].BuildingName === "undefined" 
       && typeof _regionAndBuildings[i].Region === "undefined")
            {
                console.log("Deleting");
               _regionAndBuildings.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the other way round, [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array for good values:

```
var goodRegionAndBuildings = _regionAndBuildings.filter(function(item) {
    // assumes not-empty strings are good
    // everything else is bad
    return (
        item.ModifiedOn !== "" &&
        item.BuildingName !== "" &&
        item.Latitude !== "" &&
        item.Longitude !== "" &&
        item.Region !== ""
    );
});
```

Comment: What is the trade off in performance, if say 95% of the data is good and 5% is bad?

Answer (score 1):

In you given example

```
{
    "ModifiedOn": "2015-04-29 11:17:28.0",
    "BuildingName": "Kings Landing",
    "Latitude": "23.818051",
    "Longitude": "-.154871",
}
```

property `BuildingName` or `Region` is missing. It is more appropriate to usu `hasOwnProperty` instead of `_regionAndBuildings[i].BuildingName === undefined`

```
for (var i = 0; i < _regionAndBuildings.length; i++){
    if (!(_regionAndBuildings[i].hasOwnProperty('BuildingName')) && !(_regionAndBuildings[i].hasOwnProperty('Region'))) {
        console.log("Deleting");
        _regionAndBuildings.splice(i, 1);
     }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xhwrtws/)